# Creating installer for ArcGIS toolbar with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: arcobjects, visual-studio, arcgis-9.2

I'm working on a small toolbar for ArcGIS 9.2, Windows XP, using Visual Studio .NET 2005. I followed Esri's instructions for creating an installer: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/0df20605-b457-42d6-b63c-341a3824474a.htm. I can install the resulting .msi or .exe file on the workstation where the toolbar was developed, without being an admin. When I or our admin. tried to install it on other computers in the office, the install failed with an error code 2869. A web search ('install error 2869') returned mostly vague, unhelpful, and irrelevant results.

Has anyone else experienced this error when creating an installer, and how did you resolve it?

Comment: What version of msiexec is installed on the dev and target machines?(type `msiexec /?` at command prompt) What OS and servicepack is the target machine?

Comment: Both have msiexec 4.5.6001.22159 & Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1):

The machines where you deploy the toolbar must be at the same version & service pack or lower. In your solution expand the References and highlight all the Esri references. In the properties for the Esri references make sure the property for 'Specific Version' is set to False. Also, the user installing the toolbar must have priviledges to write to the registry.

Comment: I can't find a 'Specific Version' property for the ESRI.ArcGIS references. The instructions mentioned above said to change the 'Exclude' property to True and 'Register' to vsdraDoNotRegister.

Comment: The Specific Version property is in the main project's References not the Detected Dependencies list for your setup project. In the solution explorer click 'Show All Files' button. Expand the References item. Right-click on an Esri reference and select 'Properties'. Specific Version should be in there. Set all to False for Esri references then rebuild.

Comment: I found 1 ESRI reference set to True. Changed it to False and rebuilt solution. Gave the .msi to our IT admin. to install. I still returns the 2869 error code.